# How to make multiple objects in android kotlin using for-loop

Tags: android, loops, kotlin

I struggle with one thing where I need to loop 7 days in one of my Kotlin fragments. I know how to loop objects or variables in Kotlin.

```
var i=0    
for(i<7){
  // loop 7 objects in the activity create them and show it to the user
}
```

And I already have an object that I want to loop. `var day = root.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.day_1)`. My question is how to loop it so the user would see all seven looped objects.

Ask me if something is unclear.

Comment: use the `android-studio` tag for questions specifically related to questions about the IDE, not just for questions making use of the IDE :)

Comment: Ok,  I didn't know this. I just recently started coding. My fault

Comment: not a problem :)

Comment: also, as far as I know, there's no way to achieve what you want to achieve using a for loop, i don't believe there's a way to use that loop variable for the findViewById part

Comment: I think you should step back from the implementation details like "for loops" and "objects". Instead, tell us what you want the UI to look like and what the user should be able to do. Use a program to draw it for us.

Comment: For lists like this, you should look at `RecyclerView` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to (sensibly) dynamically create an ID. A better approach is to define the array of IDs beforehand, then loop through it.

```
val ids = arrayOf(R.id.day_1, R.id.day_2, R.id.day_3, R.id.day_4, R.id.day_5, R.id.day_6, R.id.day_7)
for (id in ids) {
  val view = root.findViewById<LinearLayout>(id)
  // view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a reference to the containing view you can iterate through it's children:

```
val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.myLayout)
for (i in 0 until layout.childCount) {
  val view = layout.getChildAt(i)
  // view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For so few objects, it may not be worth it, but you can use reflection to obtain an ID value:

```
fun getViewIdByName(name: String): Int? =
    try {
        R.id::class.java.getField(name).getInt(null)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException){
        null
    }
```

Then you can use the above function in your loop:

```
for (i in 1..7) {
    val id = getViewIdByName("day_$i")
    id?: continue // maybe log error
    val day = root.findViewById<LinearLayout>(id)
    //...
}
```

Comment: getIdentifier should probably be used over raw reflection